# Centering full-width Fixed Nav Header

Tags: html, css, fixed, centering

I've been struggling with this. I've tried a variety of things, and i've tried re-writing the entire code several times.

**HTML:**

```
  <header>
    <nav>
    <h1> Welcome</h1>    
    <ul>
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>Work</li>
    <li>About</li>
    <li>Contact</li>
        </ul></nav>
    </header>
```

**CSS:**

```
header nav {
    border: 2px solid green;

 width: 100%;
 position: fixed;
 font-size: 1.3em;
 color: red;
 z-index: 10;

}

header nav ul {
 list-style: none;
 width: 90%;
 margin:0 auto;

}

header nav ul li {
 display: inline;
 width: 100%;
 margin: 0 auto;
}
```

I am trying to center the `li` and the `h1` within the `nav`, but I'm only able to indent it seems.

So here's a fiddle as well.

http://jsfiddle.net/Ex3sh/

Answer (score 1):

Apply `text-align:center;` for the header

check this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/Ex3sh/1/)

*side note: `<nav>` is used for representing the section with navigation elements, for me it looks like the `<h1>` doesn't belong there... you might want to move it out of the `nav` and place it in the header above `<nav>`*

Comment: Hahah that was too easy, I spent too much time on that. Thank you !